# Is there any way to make this use of a generic delegate simpler?

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates

I have the following methods that work:

```
Private Delegate Function WebMethodDelegate(Of TRequest, TResponse)(ByVal request As TRequest) As TResponse

Private Function CallWebMethod(Of TRequest, TResponse)(ByVal request As TRequest, ByVal theMethodToRun As WebMethodDelegate(Of TRequest, TResponse)) As TResponse

    Dim response As TResponse = Nothing

'begin pseudocode
    While somtthing is true

            response = theMethodToRun.Invoke(Request)

    End While
'end pseudocode

End Function
```

I call the above with (an ugly call):

```
Dim webMethodDeletgate As New WebMethodDelegate(Of wsLookupServiceProxy.RequestBase, wsLookupServiceProxy.GetSelectedLookupInfoResponseOfTitle)(AddressOf _service.GetAllTitles)
CallWebMethod(Of wsLookupServiceProxy.RequestBase, wsLookupServiceProxy.GetSelectedLookupInfoResponseOfTitle)(request, webMethodDeletgate)
```

I thought about doing this:

```
Dim requestType As Type = GetType(wsLookupServiceProxy.RequestBase)
Dim responseType As Type = GetType(wsLookupServiceProxy.GetSelectedLookupInfoResponseOfTitle)

Dim webMethodDeletgate As New WebMethodDelegate(Of requestType, responseType)(AddressOf _service.GetAllTitles)
CallWebMethod(Of requestType, responseType)(request, webMethodDeletgate)
```

But the compiler didn't like it.

I wondered if anyone can provide a cleaner way to call the method, without having the hugely long method call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you concerned about the `CallWebMethod` or the `webMethodDelegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well by using

```
Imports wsLookupServiceProxy
```

at the top of your class you can get this down to

```
Dim webMethodDeletgate As New WebMethodDelegate(Of RequestBase, GetSelectedLookupInfoResponseOfTitle)(AddressOf _service.GetAllTitles)
CallWebMethod(request, webMethodDeletgate)
```

You can also remove the `(Of TResult, TResponse)` from the method call since those are determinable from the `webMehtodDelegate`

Comment: Thank you, but I couldn't get that to work. wsLookupServiceProxy is a web service, and I don't know how make the CallWebMethod types determinable from the WebMethodDelegate, would you be able to provide an example please. Also Not that the CallWebMethod returns a object of type TRespose.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are going to be able to shorten it much then.

Comment: I used the full namespace (xxx.xxx.wsLookupServiceProxy) and that allowed me to remove wsLookupServiceProxy from this.